# How to group duplicate query result in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this query result in SQL Server:
[image]

But i want to group those values like this:

- Name: Isaias Orozco Toledo
- Date of Birthday: 1993-07-25
- Type: Abastecimiento
- ...
- ...
- ...
- Types: Inventario en Punto de Re-Orden, Inventario Inventario Mínimo

That is to say, convert the duplicate query result to one query result.

I have something like this:

```
var getUsuarios = _context
                  .LoadStoredProc("General.GetUsuarios_Personal")
                  .ExecuteStoredProc<GetPersonalDTO>();

string[] vector = getUsuarios.Select(x => x.Alerta).ToArray();
var join = string.Join(',', vector);
```

I have other rows in my DB, but with this obviouslly, returns the same values but with comma: '', '',

I want to know if I can do that, and how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` which is in the `System.Linq` namespace.

```
var getUsuarios = _context
    .LoadStoredProc("General.GetUsuarios_Personal")
    .ExecuteStoredProc<GetPersonalDTO>();

var vector = getUsuarios.GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x.Alerta);
```

Comment: I think your solution worked for me, i had tried this: `GroupBy (x => x.Name, x.Alert)`, but it did not work haha. Now, with your solution, i think it worked for me, because now groups the duplicate names with their Alert Types, I'll keep on trying my friend, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can group by your 'main object identifier', I'm guessing the user.

```
string[] vector = getUsuarios.Select(x => x.Alerta).GroupBy(
    x => x.YourObjectIdentifiedGoesHere).ToArray();
```